# Fragment and button latency

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, soundpool

I have a scrollable tab layout with 4 fragments with 4 adapters. Each fragment has a few buttons in them that use a `SoundPool` to play short mp3 clips. It works for the most part (aside from a few crashes after button clicks) but I noticed scrolling from one fragment to another is taking a long time. Also I was using `MediaPlayer` items before switching to `SoundPool` based on what I've seen for using short clips and now it takes a while to load the initial page and sometimes clicking crashes the app (which it also did with the `MediaPlayer`). So I want to make the scrolling more smooth (I do have hardware acceleration turned on), pages to load faster, and buttons to not crash. Right now I have:

In MainActivity:

```
public static class MiscFragment extends Fragment {

    public MiscFragment() {

    }
    View rootView;
    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment,
                container, false);

        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabgridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MiscAdapter(getActivity()));
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

This is an inner class which is also the same as the other `Fragments` I'm using. And the corresponding `Adapter` class:

```
public class MiscAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private String[] mButtons = { "Button1", "Button2", "Button3"};

public MiscAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mButtons.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button myButton;

    if (convertView == null) {
        myButton = new Button(mContext);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(230, 150));
        myButton.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        convertView = myButton;
    } else {
        myButton = (Button) convertView;
    }

    myButton.setText(mButtons[position]);
    myButton.setId(position);
    myButton.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position));

    return convertView;
}


class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    private int position;
    final SoundPool pool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    List<Integer> streams = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final int soundID1 = pool.load(mContext, R.raw.mp3_1, 1);
    final int soundID2 = pool.load(mContext, R.raw.mp3_2, 1);
    final int soundID3 = pool.load(mContext, R.raw.mp3_3, 1);


    public MyOnClickListener(int position) {

        this.position = position;

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        position = v.getId();

        if(position == 0){
            int streamID1 = pool.play(soundID1, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            streams.add(streamID1);
        }
        if(position == 1){
            int streamID2 = pool.play(soundID2, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            streams.add(streamID2);
        }
        if(position == 2){
            int streamID3 = pool.play(soundID3, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            streams.add(streamID3);
        }


    }

}
```

This Adapter class is cloned for the other `Fragments`. I think a problem may be repetitive use of either the `GridView` and/or `SoundPool` in every adapter but I'm not sure. Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Never load something on the main thread if you can help it. Why are you loading a sound pool each instead of sharing it. Most likely the loading takes too long. You should load the sound pool on a background thread and only once.